# Identity Roles with Database First ASP.Net MVC 5 and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to follow tutorials online to help me get roles setup in my MVC project, but seem to be failing to understand everything. My company required that I create my project Database First, rather than code first, so my roles already exist in my dbContext. I do not want to create a controller to Index, Create, Edit, etc. my Roles, at least not at this step, but I ***DO*** want to know what userGroup my users belong to, to then refer to their userGroup as their role.

So, I have two Models; one for users and one for userGroups (essentially a "roles" table):

```
public partial class User : IdentityUser
{
    public int UKey { get; set; }
    public int UgKey { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool UseBrightreeAuth { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

public partial class UserGroup
{
    public int UgKey { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

I have a Account Controller that handles the "logging in" of my website:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel login)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Form is not valid; please review and try again.";
            return View("Login");
        }

        using (var wfc = new WorkflowContext())
        {                
            if(wfc.User.Where(x => x.Username == login.Username).Any())
            {
                    //ignore the bad logic/LINQ, it's temporary...

                    var UserManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(wfc));
                    UserManager.AddToRole("UserName", "UserRole");
            }
            else
            {
                    ViewBag.Error = "Credentials invalid. Please try again.";
                            return View("Login");
            }
        }
}
```

the following line of code will not compile, saying wfc is not a valid argument, but I am not sure what I should be using instead?

```
//Where wfc is the Context that contains my User and UserGroup Tables
var UserManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(wfc));
```

I get the error

> Cannot convert from "Workflow.Models.WorkflowContext" to "System.Data.Entity.DbContext"

Is there a better way to add a user to a role or am I misunderstanding the process? Thanks.

Comment: Could you show the implementation of WorkflowContext? Which line does throw the exception?

Comment: @Win oops, I appologize. This is actually a build error.  the argument of using `wfc` being used in `var UserManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(wfc));` has a red underline/compilation error.